# Pythonic way to get minimum nonzero value or zero, if it does not exist

Tags: python, list, minimum

I have a problem finding the correct way to do  this in python:

I have a list of two numbers which are Positive numbers including Zero

This is what I want:

- If both numbers are greater than zero, I want the minimum one
- If one is Zero and the other is greater than zero, I want the one that is greater than zero
- and if both are zero, I want zero

How do I do this without writing Ifs: following would be an example:

```
if list[0]>0 and list[1]>0 : answer = min(list)
if list[0] >0 xor list[1]>0 : answer = max(list)
else: answer = 0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share what you've already tried? At least this is more a mathematical problem. Have a look at `min()`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for code, without showing any attempt at code by the OP themselves, nor showing an indication of what their actual problem is.

Comment: The irony is that the question asks to do this without writing `if`s, but it uses three ifs to post the problem. And given how close Python is to normal English (compared to various other programming language), that seems rather ironic.

Comment: @js-on Thanks for your time. It is a simple problem if I write a couple of Ifs, as I edited the post, however, I am looking for pythonic ways. a kind of one liner

Comment: @9769953 You are right, but as I mentioned, I thought there might be a simpler way to do that.

Comment: Avoiding the use of *if* doesn't make your code Pythonic. It just makes it hard to understand

Comment: So the minimum of nonzero values except return zero when all zeros. `answer = min((x for x in yourlist if x != 0), default=0)`

Comment: `min` and `max` have if-s behind the scene, so I don't see the point of the question (or the current solutions). if-elif-elif might be perfectly here, and would  make it very clear what the various cases are (I don't list else here, since there are also negative numbers, which are not involved here, and thus would end up in an else clause.)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
a, b = lst
min(a or b, b or a)
```

Another:

```
min(lst) or max(lst)
```

Both use that `x or y` results in `x` if it's true (nonzero) and `y` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Filter out your zeros and take the min of that.  If the resulting iterable is empty have `min()` return a default value.

```
answer = min((x for x in yourlist if x != 0), default=0)
```

And with no explicit `if`s:

```
answer = min(filter(None, yourlist), default=0)
```

Comment: I see an *if* in there ;-) OP doesn't like *if*

Comment: @LancelotduLac Challenge accepted :)

Comment: Thanks guys. I did saw a couple of solutions like the first one you mentioned, however, I cannot remember the "default=0" in them. Nice tip! @LancelotduLac

Comment: :)) @StevenRumbalski